# Prisoner's Dilemma in VB.NET - Compilation error related to "Else If"

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to build a Prisoner's Dilemma game in VB.NET for a school project and I found this strange behavior I don't understand.

I have 2 buttons for the player, "Co-op" and "Defect" both with an identical code structure:

```
Private Sub btnDefect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDefect.Click
    Oponent()
    MovePlayer = "Defect"

    If MoveOponent = "Coop" Then
        scorePlayer += 50
        scoreOponent -= 50
    Else
        If MoveOponent = "Defect" Then
            scorePlayer -= 10
            scoreOponent -= 10
        End If
    End If


    scores()

End Sub
```

I know the ELSE - IF is unnecesary, but I wrote it that way to be clearer and more readable. The problem is that if both buttons have that ELSE - IF I get a compilation error and cannot run the game from Visual Studio (the .exe in the bin folder works OK though). Now if I remove the ELSE - IF from **either** button and just leave a regular ELSE it works perfectly. But if I remove it from both, same error occurs.

The error I get is:

> Could not copy the file "obj\x86\Debug\PrisonersDilemma.exe" because
>   it was not found. PrisonersDilemma

But I looked for that .exe file, and it's right there!

Any idea why this might be? I can get it to work by leaving just one ELSE - IF, but I'd like to know what's wrong.

Here's the full code for reference:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim MovePlayer As String
    Dim MoveOponent As String
    Dim scorePlayer As Integer
    Dim scoreOponent As Integer

    Sub scores()
        lblscoreOponent.Text = scoreOponent
        lblscorePlayer.Text = scorePlayer
    End Sub
    Sub Oponent()
        If MovePlayer = "" Then
            MoveOponent = "Coop"
        Else
            MoveOponent = MovePlayer
        End If

        lblMoveOponent.Text = MoveOponent
        lblMoveOponent.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnCoop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCoop.Click
        Oponent()
        MovePlayer = "Coop"

        If MoveOponent = "Coop" Then
            scorePlayer += 10
            scoreOponent += 10
        Else
            scorePlayer += 50
            scoreOponent -= 50
        End If

        scores()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDefect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDefect.Click
        Oponent()
        MovePlayer = "Defect"

        If MoveOponent = "Coop" Then
            scorePlayer += 50
            scoreOponent -= 50
        Else
            If MoveOponent = "Defect" Then
                scorePlayer -= 10
                scoreOponent -= 10
            End If
        End If


        scores()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!!

Comment: That error message has little to do with your code.  You'll need to disable your virus scanner or make an exclusion.  If it is Avast then just completely uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

1: When you compile, if there is an error, your EXE in your bin folder will not be replaced. Your EXE is the last successful build, that why you get the questions, "There was an error in the build process, would you like to run the last successful build?" If you say yes, this will run that EXE.

2: Seems like I have seen the "Could not be found" error on occasion with 2012, I think it is an issue with Visual Studio.  Usually I try again and it is fine.  If you are running the EXE from the bin folder, make sure it is not running before you compile.  It will block the ability to copy it.

3: If you want help figuring out why you get the comiplation error, you must show that code, not the code that works!